# Is it possible to reserve the direction of the card-reveal on Materializecss?

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

I'm looking at the card-reveal component of the materializecss framework shown here: https://codepen.io/JP_juniordeveloperaki/pen/YXRyvZ the official doc is here: http://next.materializecss.com/cards.html

For my application, I have moved the `<div class="card-content">` to the top to look like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YaqYOj

So I was wondering whether or not it was possible to make the card-reveal animation go from top to bottom, like the top card-content is a curtain that pulls down to reveal more information.

Thanks

Comment: Of course  , you can check my answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing `transform` property of this element `.card .card-reveal {}`.

And i add `extra class` to change the `transform` property make the **top card-content is a curtain that pulls down to reveal more information***

***Here is the working  code***

> **Note:** Also add `display: block` to `.card .card-image img` fix the `bottom gap` in your demo.

```js
$('.card-content').click(()=>{
  $('.card-reveal').addClass('card-closing');
});

$('.card-reveal .card-title-custom').click(()=>{
  $('.card-reveal').removeClass('card-closing');
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 450px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.card .card-image img {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.card .card-reveal {
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    top: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block !important;
    transform: translateY(-200%) !important;
    transition: transform .6s;
    will-change: opacity, transform;
}
.card .card-reveal.card-closing {
    transform: translateY(-100%) !important;
    display: block !important;
}
.grey-text.text-darken-4 {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-alpha.4/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="main">
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
      <p><a href="#">This is a link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
      <img class="activator-custom" src="http://materializecss.com/images/office.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="card-reveal">
      <span class="card-title-custom grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
      <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/AnzilkhaN/pen/NYNORx)